# Проблема с переносом текста

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

проблема, собственно, в коде, почему не переносится текст? Слово: "Русагроимпортом" выходит за пределы и не переносится

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  max-width: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Гордость агрохолдинга – Фабрика мясной гастрономии «Ариант», открытая в июле 2014 года. В ее основу еще на стадии проектирования, осуществленного австрийской компанией BERTSCHlaska и отечественным «Русагроимпортом», был заложен принцип максимальной технологичности
  и конкурентных преимуществ. Основу производственной линии и вспомогательных структур составило оборудование ведущих мировых производителей: KOTA, BEGARAT, SIMEM, KATERPILLAR и других. В итоге появилась фабрика, не имеющая себе равных в техническом оснащении.
  Перерабатывающие агрегаты премиум-класса, экологически чистое сырье, лучшие рецепты продукта, самые современные технологии мира. Всё это позволило продукции под маркой «Ариант» успешно конкурировать с европейской продукцией и выходить на мировые рынки
  сбыта. Кроме собственно производства, на площади 15 тыс. кв. м расположился логистический центр, помещения для обвалки, эффективные очистные сооружения и собственный энергоблок. Эти факторы позволяют «Арианту» не просто снизить себестоимость своей продукции,
  но стать вне конкуренции в качестве, а это решающий аргумент в борьбе за потребителя.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас там неразрывный пробел(`&nbsp;`), посмотрите результат замены пробелов на тире в этом примере

```js
document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML.split(' ').join('-')
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  max-width: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Гордость агрохолдинга – Фабрика мясной гастрономии «Ариант», открытая в июле 2014 года. В ее основу еще на стадии проектирования, осуществленного австрийской компанией BERTSCHlaska и отечественным «Русагроимпортом», был заложен принцип максимальной технологичности
  и конкурентных преимуществ. Основу производственной линии и вспомогательных структур составило оборудование ведущих мировых производителей: KOTA, BEGARAT, SIMEM, KATERPILLAR и других. В итоге появилась фабрика, не имеющая себе равных в техническом оснащении.
  Перерабатывающие агрегаты премиум-класса, экологически чистое сырье, лучшие рецепты продукта, самые современные технологии мира. Всё это позволило продукции под маркой «Ариант» успешно конкурировать с европейской продукцией и выходить на мировые рынки
  сбыта. Кроме собственно производства, на площади 15 тыс. кв. м расположился логистический центр, помещения для обвалки, эффективные очистные сооружения и собственный энергоблок. Эти факторы позволяют «Арианту» не просто снизить себестоимость своей продукции,
  но стать вне конкуренции в качестве, а это решающий аргумент в борьбе за потребителя.
</p>
```

Вот пример без ошибки:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  max-width: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Гордость агрохолдинга – Фабрика мясной гастрономии «Ариант», открытая в июле 2014 года. В ее основу еще на стадии проектирования, осуществленного австрийской компанией BERTSCHlaska и отечественным «Русагроимпортом», был заложен принцип максимальной технологичности
  и конкурентных преимуществ. Основу производственной линии и вспомогательных структур составило оборудование ведущих мировых производителей: KOTA, BEGARAT, SIMEM, KATERPILLAR и других. В итоге появилась фабрика, не имеющая себе равных в техническом оснащении.
  Перерабатывающие агрегаты премиум-класса, экологически чистое сырье, лучшие рецепты продукта, самые современные технологии мира. Всё это позволило продукции под маркой «Ариант» успешно конкурировать с европейской продукцией и выходить на мировые рынки
  сбыта. Кроме собственно производства, на площади 15 тыс. кв. м расположился логистический центр, помещения для обвалки, эффективные очистные сооружения и собственный энергоблок. Эти факторы позволяют «Арианту» не просто снизить себестоимость своей продукции,
  но стать вне конкуренции в качестве, а это решающий аргумент в борьбе за потребителя.
</p>
```